# Get object keyname vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a data with object, when im using v-for:

```
data: {
  comp: {
   title: {
   ...
   }, 
   title2: {
   ...
   }, 
   title3: {
   ...
   }, 
}

..

div(v-for="item in comp" @click="method(item)")
```

How i can get name of item (title, title2, title3) in method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    comp: {
      title: {}, 
      title2: {}, 
      title3: {}, 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    itemClicked(item) {
      console.log(item);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(val,key) in comp" @click="itemClicked(key)">
    {{ key }} - {{ val }}
  </div>
</div>
```